# in angular how to add nested object to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-module

I'm a complete angular noob so please forgive the rudimentary question.

I have a post/comment structure for my model that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "awesome post",
        "desc": "asdf",
        "comment_set": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "desc": "another awesome comment",
            }
        ]
     }
]
```

My angular template looks like the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.created_at" class="media media-clearfix-xs">
<div>{{post.title}}</div>
<ul class="comments">
                                <li ng-repeat="comment in post.comment_set  | orderBy:created_at" clas="media">
                                  <div>{{comment.desc}}
                                </li>
                                <li class="comment-form">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.addComment()">
                                    <input ng-model="post.comment_set.desc" type="text" class="form-control" />
</form>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i></input>
                </span>

                                  </div>
                                </li>
                              </ul>

</li>
```

My angular component looks like this:

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: '/static/common/angular/phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http',
      function PhoneListController($http) {
        var self = this;

        self.addComment = function() {
            self.push({desc:post.comment_set.desc});
          };

        $http.get('api/posts/').then(function(response) {
          self.phones = response.data;

        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

**What am I missing that will add comments to the comments ng-repeat?**

Comment: I don't know it it matters but you are missing a `</div>` on the 5th line.

Comment: where is `created_at` related to? Haven't seen it in the controller or in json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addComment function is incorrect.

You should have:

```
ng-submit="addComment(post.comment_set)"
```

and:

```
ng-model="$ctrl.desc"
```

Then, addComment() should be:

```
self.addComment(comment_set){
    comment_set.push({desc: self.desc, id: <ID_HERE>});
    self.desc = null;
}
```

This way, you reset the desc variable so you can add a new comment

Comment: I added $ctrl in front of addComment(post.comment_set) and it worked!!!!